# How can I close a popup window in Android application

Tags: android, android-studio, popupwindow

I have an activity which starts a popup window when a button is clicked. I have created a PopupWindow activity and also the appropriate resource xml file. I added a button to the xml file (close popup) button. and I don't know what code should I use for closing the popup window. Here's my PopupWindow class:

```
public class AuthorsPopup extends Activity {
    public Button closePopupButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceSlate) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceSlate);
        setContentView(R.layout.authors_popup);

        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

        int width = dm.widthPixels;
        int height = dm.heightPixels;
        //multiply times 0.8 of screen size
        getWindow().setLayout((int) (width * 0.8), (int) (height * 0.8));

        closePopupButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.close_button);
        closePopupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View popupView) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: just add finish()

Comment: As @Godfather stated `finish()` method  will close the `AuthorsPopup` Activity...but I am assuming you will want to Open another activity as `AuthorsPopup` is being closed? Then you will need to add the `Intent` to start another activity.

Comment: I see no `PopupWindow` in your code

Answer (score 3):

To close the "PopUpWindow" or the `Activity` you would use `finish()` method inside the `onClick` of the button

This is the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#finish()) for the `finish()` method as well.